# SendTextMessage Successfully but not receiving on All Mobiles

Tags: android

In my Android Application, using Android sendtextmessage and sendmultiparttextmessage the message "sent broadcast" received successfully but most of recipients don't receive message. The message also shows in sent items of default message handling application.

Please help to figure out the issue.